# Substituting routes in text content in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am setting up a feature on my site that requires displaying content that is stored in the database. This content will frequently have links to other resources on the site.

Stored in the db:

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit <a href='http://mysite.com/somecontroller/someaction'>amet</a>."
```

For debugging and other reasons, I don't want to hard code that url. I want to replace `http://mysite.com/somecontroller/someaction` with `UrlHelper.Action("somecontroller", "someaction")`.

I could write a replacement based on my own made up convention. That would be easy and accomplish what I want to do. However, I thought I might be missing some cleaner or more standard solution. So, is there a cleaner more maintainable way to do this, or should I go ahead with a convention based replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacement is probably best, and easiest to maintain. Another way to handle it is to allow ASP.Net to parse the code. You'd have to create your own VirtualPathProvider which would allow Views to be pulled from the database in addition to the file system. Then you could use

```
Html.RenderPartial(nameVirtualPathProviderUnderstands);
```

Which would render the string in the database as if it were a file. Although this isn't very safe, and you would need to modify the content before the VirtualPathProvider rendered it. [Here](http://blog.rocketbase.co.uk/2011/04/asp-net-mvc-virtual-path-provider/) is a guide which explains how to implement your own VirtualPathProvider.

Comment: I think I will just go with a magic string replacement method. However, I think I will save your idea about a custom `VirtualPathProvider` as a possible future refactor.

Comment: @Dan the biggest downside is who is entering the content, and how it will get out of sync with the code. I had to create my own PathProvider to pull the Views out of the resources compiled with the dlls. It turned out well, but I think you'd have more problems.

Comment: For now, the content will end up flowing through some part of my staff. Before I let users edit, I know I will need to refactor the string convention out of existence or provide some pretty robust ui tools and validation.

Comment: @Dan be very careful, that just sounds like a recipe for XSS attacks.

Comment: I think it is a recipe for xss attack. In this case, however, the content will be internally generated. If it were going to echo back user input, I would be a terrified of this :)

Answer (score 0):

I made a 'hack' like so in one of my projects:

```
  public class UrlLinks
  {
       public static string HomeLink { get; protected set; }

       public static UrlLinks()
       {
            HomeLink = Link<HomeController>(x => x.Index());
       }

       protected static string Link<TControllerType>(Expression<Func<TControllerType, object>> expression)
       {
            return "methodName";
       }
  }
```

Basically, the link would be constructed from the typename and the method name via the expression and generic parameter, so if I refactored, I would pick up the new method and controller names.

Then in my view I could do this - eliminating the need for magic strings:

```
  <a href="@UrlLinks.HomeLink">Home</a>
```